# Update a date-time field (from system) but don't make it visible to user

Tags: django-forms

The following is my "view" which renders a form through "editpost.html". I want to update the timestamp (datetime field) to be edited by the system time, but don't want that to be visible to the user. I tried using "hidden" keyword in the modelform definition Meta class, but that does not update the time correctly. I tried doing it in the template but doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
def editpost(request, postid):    
    blog = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=postid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogPostForm(request.POST, instance=blog)
        blog = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/%s' % str(postid))
    else:
        form = BlogPostForm(initial={'timestamp': datetime.now()}, instance=blog)
        form.save(commit=False)
    return render_to_response("editpost.html", {'form': form, 'postid': postid}, RequestContext(request))
```

editpost.html

```
{% block content %}
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.label_tag != "Timestamp" %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be better would be rewrite `def save(...)` of the model. You can try it:

> ```
> def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>     self.timestamp = datetime.now()
>     super(Dog,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
> ```